# c# refreshing table

Tags: c#, datagrid, datagridview, oledb

How can I refresh a table, so on a button click, the table would have refreshed data. If I changed table data, program shows old ones, so I must restart the program to have refreshed data in the table.

[image: table]

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Please post your code and explain where you are stuck.

Comment: How about you start off by reading this page [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: I stucked hire, everything is working fine, except that i have old data in table.

Answer (score 3):

A DataTable is a disconnected object, meaning that it can't be automatically updated if someone else change the data in the database. To refresh the table content you need to recall the code that has originally filled the table

Comment: Simple but effective.